# Google Chrome broke ShellExecute()?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, shellexecute

For years I've been using ShellExecute() API to launch the default web browser from within my applications. Like this:

```
ShellExecute( hwnd, _T("open"), 
    _T("http://www.winability.com/home/"), 
    NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL );
```

It's been working fine until a couple of weeks ago, when Google released its Chrome browser. Now, if Chrome is installed on the computer, the ShellExecute API no longer opens a web page.

Has anyone figured out yet how to solve this problem? (Short of detecting Chrome and displaying a message telling the user it's Chrome's fault?)

EDIT: the code provided by Sergey seems to work, so I've accepted it as "the" answer. Except that I don't like the call to WinExec: MSDN reads that WinExec is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit applications. IOW, it may stop working with any Service Pack. I did not try it, but I would not be surprised if it has already stopped working with Windows x64, since it does not support 16-bit applications at all. So, instead of WinExec, I'm going to use ShellExecute, with the path taken from the registry like Sergey's code does, and the URL as the argument. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this works perfectly on my machine with Chrome set as the default browser. You *might* want to see if there's something else installed on the broken machines...

Comment: It did not work on my machine, but with the trick of launching the .htm-associated application it works now, so I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: WinExec actually remains in x64, all the way to current Windows afaik and have tested. I don't believe they've had a good reason to remove it, so have just left it in.

Comment: And I have a feeling that this may have something to do with Chrome opening links in a background tab. Perhaps the user doesn't notice, or perhaps this tab is mistakenly hidden. It seems Opera has also been afflicted by this problem, according to sparse user reports. Myself, I have not seen such a failure, so believe the root cause is severe shell association corruption on some PCs, assuming it is not just them 'missing' the background tab being opened.

Comment: Also please note, as I noted on a comment of the answer, to be careful with launching the browser elevated, if your application is running elevated. This is an undesired state for the browser, obviously. Applies to NT6+, only, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that works across all browsers. The trick is to call WinExec if ShellExecute fails.

```
HINSTANCE GotoURL(LPCTSTR url, int showcmd)
{
    TCHAR key[MAX_PATH + MAX_PATH];

    // First try ShellExecute()
    HINSTANCE result = 0;

    CString strURL = url;

    if ( strURL.Find(".htm") <0 && strURL.Find("http") <0 )
        result = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), url, NULL, NULL, showcmd);

    // If it failed, get the .htm regkey and lookup the program
    if ((UINT)result <= HINSTANCE_ERROR) {

        if (GetRegKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, _T(".htm"), key) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            lstrcat(key, _T("\\shell\\open\\command"));

            if (GetRegKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,key,key) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                TCHAR *pos;
                pos = _tcsstr(key, _T("\"%1\""));
                if (pos == NULL) {                     // No quotes found
                    pos = strstr(key, _T("%1"));       // Check for %1, without quotes
                    if (pos == NULL)                   // No parameter at all...
                        pos = key+lstrlen(key)-1;
                    else
                        *pos = '\0';                   // Remove the parameter
                }
                else
                    *pos = '\0';                       // Remove the parameter

                lstrcat(pos, _T(" \""));
                lstrcat(pos, url);
                lstrcat(pos, _T("\""));
                result = (HINSTANCE) WinExec(key,showcmd);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I can concur that the premise here seems to be the most effective to use - and I had to do some experimentation to determine such. If ShellExecute fails, then fall back. Note that you can fall back to the HTTP protocol instead of .HTM handler, BUT that is what ShellExecute *should* be doing, so you would likely encounter a secondary failure if you change the code to do that.

There is also another issue: When launching the browser from an elevated process in NT 6+, the browser itself is launched elevated. This is an undesired state. There are ways to work around this, but that !topic

Answer (score 0):

After hearing reports of ShellExecute failing on a minority of systems, I implemented a function similar to the example given by Sergey Kornilov. This was about a year ago. Same premise - Do a direct HKCR lookup of the .HTM file handler.

However, it turns out that some users have editors (e.g. UltraEdit) that register themselves to 'open' .htm files (instead of 'edit' them). Thus, *if* ShellExecute fails, this secondary method will also fail in those cases. It opens the editor, as the shell association errantly instructs.

**Thus, the user should use the HTTP handler instead, or at least in preference of the HTML handler.**